# Angular multiple imports

Tags: angular, typescript, optimization, import, redundancy

**[EDIT]: My bad, I'm a bit tired and I've mixed two ideas in my mind resulting in a question which doesn't really mean much ... I'll blame it on the coffee! :P**

This is more of a knowledge question rather than an actual problem, but...
I'm currently developing an angular web application and, as I started "messing" with tests I realized most of the tests fail because I didn't include the components in the `component-name.ts` file while i import them in `app.module.ts`, yet I call custom components. 
(E.G.: `<app-menu></app-menu>`  Or  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`)

Now, the solution is pretty easy: just import the modules and it's done, but it made me wonder... performance wise is it worth to import them?
How does Angularjs deals with re-importing the same thing multiple times?
For instance: let's say I 
`import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` in `app.module.ts`

and that then I 

`import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` in `./menu/menu.module.ts`

Does angular removes the second import in compile phase or does it simply ignores it?

Comment: why do you need to import the app routing twice? I think you only need it once (the top) for the app.module.

Comment: sorry, I've put the wrong module, i meant the RouterModule to be able to use router-outlet

Comment: oh yeah I didn't fully understand the question, anyways you got an answer already ;)

Comment: Eh, it was my bad, I described it poorly... heavy day :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply explained  here:

https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

you should not import multiple times a module, but it's necessary when you have to make that module visible to every sub-components -- and this is NOT a RE-import --

Answer (score 0):

The article in the 1st answer also points to the angular docs:
https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice

To summarize, Angular is caching the modules, so when it sees a module being imported again by some other module, it just moves on.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34553529)